# Delete API not working in nodejs 10.15.3. Getting as "400 Bad Request". It is working in nodejs 8.15.3. What is the fix for node 10?

Tags: node.js

There is a delete API link as api/private/v1/configuration/config and sending a body as [{"name": "public:space", "key": "keyvalue"}] with DELETE.
The headers used is

```
Host: dev.corp:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-CSRF-Token: ae63017624d7315328a52544f923995f
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://dev.corp:8000/feedback-plugin/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,de;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ko;q=0.7,en-IN;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.5,zh;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.3,ja;q=0.2,zh-CN;q=0.1,kn;q=0.1,fr-CA;q=0.1,la;q=0.1
Cookie: splashCookieConsentId=e011cd34-b3b2-44c9-bb48-0cb1da07626a; _swa_v_ses.1a649b30-efbc-d34c-9f20-00ff0ace414e.02a5=*; X-CSRF-Token=ae63017624d7315328a52544f923995f; _pk_id.1a649b30-efbc-d34c-9f20-00ff0ace414e.02a5=a3c49cd9ca99810d.1560162024.0.1560241425..; _swa_v_id.1a649b30-efbc-d34c-9f20-00ff0ace414e.02a5=c13ce6e4611014d2.1560162025.5.1560241425.1560232562.; buildSessionId=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.fInmr0dmgYobYI4R01zTanmdM3NnX2fmg2uQ1-j8Iko; userSessionId=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXJ0IjoxNTYwMjQxNDIxOTYyLCJpYXQiOjE1NjAyNDE0MzIsImV4cCI6MTU2MDI0MzIzMn0.ccpf-BBB8u4JZneg0GDfearz0SsHDsUSo9zlelI6u7A
Content-Type:application/json
```

Tried to add body parser

```
app.use('/configuration/config', [bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}), api.token]);
```

and also tried using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in header, but no use.

getting `400 Bad Request` always in delete API for node js 10.
How this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
// Add this module to your package.json & do npm install
const morgan = require('morgan');

// Will log calls on the express side
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// No need to do this every call, do it once
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Handles the DELETE route specifically
app.delete('/configuration/config', api.token, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("/configuration/config called without problems");
  // TODO: BODY of function
});
```

If there is a problem, it's likely in the code of `api.token` and what it is meant to achieve. Also, you need to make sure that the app listens at the  `api/private/v1` endpoint.

Side-note: `Content-Type:application/json`, maybe add a space after `:` ?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
--max-http-header-size=80000
```

it went from 80k in 8.x to 8k in 10.x